# Autodesk Forge - Wrench Sample Application

Tags: autodesk-forge

Can anyone help me with this please, I've created an App on Forge and updated the Client_ID and Client_Secret in the Wrench example found here:
https://github.com/akenson/da-wrench-config

I'm trying to run the Autodesk Forge - Wrench sample application by setting the Interaction project as the startup project.
When I run the application and select option 2 - Upload data set
I get the following error:

```
Running 'Upload data set'
Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException: Missing required parameter 'clientId' when calling TwoLeggedApi->Authenticate
   at Autodesk.Forge.TwoLeggedApi.AuthenticateAsyncWithHttpInfo(String clientId, String clientSecret, String grantType, Scope[] scope)
   at Autodesk.Forge.TwoLeggedApi.AuthenticateAsync(String clientId, String clientSecret, String grantType, Scope[] scope)
   at Interaction.OAuthController.Get2LeggedTokenAsync(Scope[] scopes) in C:\Users\ian_w\Desktop\da-wrench-config-master\DaWrenchConfig\Interaction\Publisher.cs:line 344
   at Interaction.OAuthController.GetInternalAsync() in C:\Users\ian_w\Desktop\da-wrench-config-master\DaWrenchConfig\Interaction\Publisher.cs:line 330
   at Interaction.Publisher.UploadDataSetAsync() in C:\Users\ian_w\Desktop\da-wrench-config-master\DaWrenchConfig\Interaction\Publisher.cs:line 224
   at Interaction.Program.RunCommand(Publisher publisher, String commandIndex) in C:\Users\ian_w\Desktop\da-wrench-config-master\DaWrenchConfig\Interaction\Program.cs:line 87
   at Interaction.Program.RunLoop(Publisher publisher) in C:\Users\ian_w\Desktop\da-wrench-config-master\DaWrenchConfig\Interaction\Program.cs:line 75
   at Interaction.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ian_w\Desktop\da-wrench-config-master\DaWrenchConfig\Interaction\Program.cs:line 44
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the error message the client id (and possibly secret) is not specified and our client sdk needs those to access the Forge services - go [here](https://github.com/akenson/da-wrench-config/blob/ee9f5297fd0d82a9c56488b0318f4caaada339c2/DaWrenchConfig/Interaction/appsettings.json) to set them up as environment variables.